# REST request works in RestClient but not PostMan/Java

Tags: java, json, rest, postman

Having a request fail in postman/java but works in RestClient.. here is the request and attached is a screenshot of the error.

This is a POST request

{
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "simulate_user": "test",
    "sourcetabledesc": "TestList100",
    "contacts": [{
        "organization": "CKT",
        "workPhone": "12315423",
        "firstName": "Tester0",
        "zip": "1231",
        "stateProv": "Dasdas",
        "lastName": "Torrance",
        "address2": "BlaBlaBla Ble Ble Ble 1231",
        "address3": "BlaBlaBla Ble Ble Ble 1231",
        "emailAddress": "test",
        "contactid": "DS21029",
        "country": "United States",
        "title": "Driver",
        "address1": "BlaBlaBla Ble Ble Ble 1231",
        "city": "Pepepe"
    }, {
        "organization": "CKT",
        "workPhone": "12315423",
        "firstName": "Tester1",
        "zip": "1231",
        "stateProv": "Dasdas",
        "lastName": "Torrance",
        "address2": "BlaBlaBla Ble Ble Ble 1231",
        "address3": "BlaBlaBla Ble Ble Ble 1231",
        "emailAddress": "test",
        "contactid": "DS21029",
        "country": "United States",
        "title": "Driver",
        "address1": "BlaBlaBla Ble Ble Ble 1231",
        "city": "Pepepe"
    }]
}

[image]

My header is as below:
[image]

This is the response i am supposed to get: (Do you think it could be the single quotes in the response causing a conflict?)

{"data": "{'status':'processing','sourcetablename':'SrcAPI_20170714_13888489_7'}", "call": "UNUSED", "api_version": 1, "encoding": "utf-8"}

Comment: You are sending a raw request. Are you sure you don't want to use `GET/POST` request?

Comment: you need to supply username/password in authorization tab etc.

Comment: I have it set to send as a POST request @web-nomad

Comment: also i just tried to put username/password into auth tab and it still did not work.. same erorr @Juvanis

Comment: One of the reason could be content-type header.  Please check that.
From ss it seems like connectivity or timeout issue.  Check url too

Comment: Your header contain the Content-Type ?

Comment: yes it contains it [{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]

Comment: This may have nothing to do with your request. I had messages like this, it was a server problem. Can you try a get request on https://api.test.com/v1 ? is it accessible ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be content-type header.  Please check that.

Comment: [{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]